# Ubuntu 22 server reboots after using date --set or timedatectl set-time

Tags: ssh, remote, date

I ssh into remote server and first do

```
timedatectl set-ntp no
```

then I change the date a few times with either

```
date --set
timedatectl set-time
```

and server reboots, losing it's connection to vpn (configured to connect automatically on startup)
Does anyone know how to prevent this or how to safely change time?

Comment: So you're using Ubuntu Core 22 Server?  (*the 22 product is a specialist release based on Ubuntu 22.04 Server*)

Comment: Why does your server always have the wrong time when you login?